# What is "NK" and "PAO" in "NK LUKOIL PAO"?

Tags: adr, fidelity, ticker-symbols

[Lukoil](https://www.lukoil.com/) is a Russian listed company available in the US as an ADR under the symbol LUKOY (as far as I can tell). When I search for it on Fidelity, I see this:

[image]

What does the "NK" mean in "NK LUKOIL PAO"? I guess "PAO" is transliteration of the Cyrillic "ПАО" which in turn stands for "public joint-stock company" (abbreviated PJSC). But I have no theory as to what the "NK" stands for. In general what is the name of this entire thing: "NK LUKOIL PAO"? It is not a ticker symbol. What is it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd surmise that NK stands for "Oil Company". I note that there's also Rosneft, for example:

> NK Rosneft’ PAO (**Oil Company** Rosneft PJSC)

https://www.reuters.com/companies/ROSN.MM

> NK (**Neftyanaya Kompaniya**, or "oil company")

https://www.referenceforbusiness.com/history2/91/OAO-NK-YUKOS.html

This is corroborated by [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=Neftyanaya%20Kompaniya&op=translate)

Comment: [Correct](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лукойл#/media/Файл:LUK_OIL_Logo_kyr.svg)